# andthen Oz keyword

Tags: oz

I'm trying to write a tokenizer, but I'm getting a parse error:

```
%*************************** parse error ************************
%**
%** syntax error, unexpected T_DEFAULT, expecting T_then
%**
%** in file "/Users/xxx/Programmering/Oz/Oving1/Oz_oving1_task8.oz", line 15, column 36
%** ------------------ rejected (1 error)
```

Here's the code, I have marked line 15 and column 36 with %=ERROR=%

```
declare
fun {Tokenize L} 
   Keys Ops Token
in
   Keys = ["local", "in", "if", "then", "else", "end"]
   Ops = ["+", "-", "*", "/"]

   case Tokenize of Head|Tail then
      if {Member Head Keys} then
  Token = key(Head)
      elseif {Member Head Ops} then
  Token = op(Head)
      else
  case Head of Forste|_ then
     if Forste >= &a andthen Forste <= &z then % THIS IS LINE 15, COLUMN 36 = ..andthen [here]Forste..
        Token = atom(Forste)
     elseif
        Forste >= &A andthen Forste <= &Z then
        Token = id(Forste)
     end
  end
  Token | {Tokenize Tail}
      end
   else
      nil
   end
end
```

Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution already:

- My lists should have whitespace instead of a comma (`,`) between each element.
- In Oz, you write `>= andthen =<` not `>= andthen <=` as I did (`>` on wrong side of the `=`).
- I made a `case` on `Tokenize`, the `case` should be on the input `L`.

Cheers!